# Writing array a new python file

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have 10 files in a folder. I want to make an array with no of folder and multiply with a variable. As I am new in programming, I am not sure how to perform this. Will it be fine to perform like this,

```
import numpy as np
folder=/home/foldername/
startfile=[0]
endfile=[9]
x=[0.5]
for i in range(startfile,endfile):
    newarray=[i+x]
    i+=1
    print(newarray)
```

it is expected to print

```
newarray=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5]
```

Comment: I'm afraid the code you have posted doesn't make any sense, and it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want the number of files inside a folder, see [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). It's unlikely that you will need to use numpy, and you certainly don't need it for counting files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simpler way to get the array you want is

```
>>> newarray = [x + 0.5 for x in range(1, 10)]
>>> newarray
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

As it stands what you are trying to do instead has several mistakes.

First, range expects integers, but you give it lists:

```
>>> startfile=[0]
>>> endfile=[9]
>>> for i in range(startfile,endfile):
...   print i

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

`[0]` is a list containing `0`; just make `startfile = 0`, and likewise for `endfile`

```
>>> startfile=0
>>> endfile=9
>>> for i in range(startfile,endfile):
...   print i
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Notice this go up to *but not including* 9.

Now, you have `i+=1` in your loop, I suspect because you want tomake sure it gets incremented, but the for loop does that for you.

Finally, you have `newarray=[i+x]`, which will reset `newarray` each time round the loop. If you want to append things to a loop, do just that.

```
>>> newarray = []
>>> for i in range(startfile,endfile):
...   newarray.append(i + 0.5)
...
>>> newarray
[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5]
```

Again, note you probably want `endfile` to be one larger.

Comment: I have tried the simpler one and when I print newarray it give only [9.5]. And yes, you are right that I need endfile one larger because for the last endfile it should give endfile+0.5.

Comment: Which simpler one? I'm not clear what you mean. Don't forget `range` goes up to, but not including, the last number

Comment: I have used this one , newarray = [x + 0.5 for x in range(1, 10)].

Comment: When I do that I get `[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]` . You question mentions numpy and files/folders, so you must have some extra context I don't have. If you restart python, what does `newarray = [x + 0.5 for x in range(1, 10)]` give you?

Comment: The problem has solved after removing numpy import. Is it possible to include the last number also. Actually my file number start from 0 until 10? It is not possible to put endfile=11 to get the 10th file+0.5.

Comment: `for i in range(startfile, endfile+`):` should work if you can't change `endfile` for some reason

Comment: in case if I want my array raise 0.5 for each count of startfile until endfile what could be the procedure? with the same condition new variable suppose to be [0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5.....5.5]

Comment: I'm not cleasr what you are asking. `range` doesn't include the upper bound, so you need to take that into account.